# node-webkit native module with dll

Tags: node.js, module, native, node-webkit, node-gyp

I'm using node webkit with the [node webkit hipster seed](https://github.com/Anonyfox/node-webkit-hipster-seed)

I have build a native C++ module, using the Leap Motion SDK, which compile and work fine with node-gyp.

Now I'm trying to implement it on node webkit, but I always get "Error: no error" when I require my module. (Yes, it's recompiled with nw-gyp)

I was getting the same error when I was trying my module with node-gyp without leap sdk dlls, so I try to move my dlls in the module build directory, and in the application build directory, but no effect.

I'm using Windows 8, but I will also build on OSx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely, it work by renamming the executable to nw.exe, thanks to https://github.com/geo8bit/nodebob/pull/7